# Writing to a supplied vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write a class in which I can externally supply a vector and then the member functions within that class are able to write to the supplied vector. I can't think of how to do it, if it is possible.

I've been able to supply a vector and write to it in the constructor, but I need to be able to do it from a few other of the member functions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question get's downvoted that much? Sure, it's a beginner's question, but that doesn't make it a bad one. @FlapJack, next time maybe provide some code; show how you got to write to it from the constructor, for example.

Comment: @Robin thanks, I will do next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would look as follows:

```
class Foo {
   std::vector<int>* pvec;
public:
    Foo() : pvec(nullptr) {}
    void suppyVec(std::vector<int>& v) {
       pvec = &v;
    }
    void doSomething() {
       // process pvec
       assert(pvec != nullptr);
       std::vector<int>& vec = *pvec;
    }
};
```

or with reference, but you must do it with constructor:

```
class Foo {
   std::vector<int>& vec;
public:
    Foo(std::vector<int>& v) : vec(v) { }
    void doSomething() {
       // process vec
    }
};
```

Comment: almost.  make v and vec a non-const reference